# Apache cordova project build in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, apache-cordova

I try build my apache cordova project. It's working in Ripple but is not working "Google Android Emulator".  environment variables are correct.

[image: visual studio 2016 build]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> >Could not Get 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.
>
> >peer not authenticated

You need to import a certificate, to do this follow the below steps:

1. Open https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom in any browser.
2. Export the Certificate Authorities by following [this link](http://docs.bvstools.com/home/ssl-documentation/exporting-certificate-authorities-cas-from-a-website).
3. Copy the certificate into `JDK_HOME/jre/lib/security` folder
4. Open a cmd shell and go to  `JDK_HOME/jre/lib/security` folder
5. Import the certificate into java:

   ```
   keytool -import -alias <the short name of the server> -file <cert_file_name_you_exported.cer> -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit
   ```
6. Restart your visual studio and run the app again.